# My rss feed url is not displaying information about my website

Tags: joomla, rss

I have this as my rss feed url: http://africanquarters.com/index.php?format=feed&type=rss

It does not display my content, but displays data that has nothing to do with my daily changing content.  I'm using joomla 1.7.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The rss feed output for a given page varies depending upon the type of page (and probably withe the version of Joomla). For Joomla 1.5 the rss feed was only populated with articles that you marked as 'frontpage' (which is now called 'featured' in Joomla 1.7).

Is this the issue. The articles in the feed are 'featured' and your day in, day out changes which aren't represented in the feed are not marked as frontpage/featured?